# for_each and mem_fun_ref trouble

Tags: c++, for-loop, each

I use for_each and mem_fun_ref as a example ,but there are some error in compile ,what's the problem

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<set>
#include<iterator>
using namespace std;

class Tst
{
public:
    Tst(int a, string b):n(a),s(b)
{}

    bool operator<(const Tst& t)const
    {
        return this->n < t.n;
    }

    int GetN()const
    {
        return n;
    }   

    string GetS()const
    {   
        return s;
    }   

    void SetN(int a)
    {   
        n = a;
    }   

    void SetName(string name)
    {   
        s = name;
    }   

    void Print(void)
        {   
        cout <<"n is:" << n <<"\ts is:" << s << endl;
    }

private:
    int n;
    string s;
};

int main(void)
{
    typedef set<Tst> TstSet;
TstSet tst;

tst.insert(Tst(10, "abc"));
tst.insert(Tst(1, "def"));
for_each(tst.begin(), tst.end(), mem_fun_ref(&Tst::Print));
return true;
}
```

> :4200: 错误：对‘(std::mem_fun_ref_t) (const Tst&)’的调用没有匹配，是什么原因

Answer (score 4):

`std::set`'s contained objects are `const`, so you can only call `const` functions on them. Your `Print` function should be marked `const`.

Answer (score 0):

The function should be `const`, because `std::set` only works with `const` objects

```
void Print(void)const
{

}
```